# Sublime Text 3 Reindent with proper array parenthesis in PHP

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I Have a problem like [that](http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/80973-indent-for-parenthesis-in-php/)

but answer in link above don't helped me. I get used to reindent whole file while coding and I liked Sublime Text very much. But this bug makes me mad. So I need to reindent whole PHP files with shortcut and don't get wrong indenting.

This is how i need: [image]

And this is how it does: [image]

Comment: Maybe try [Sublime PHP Grammar](https://github.com/gerardroche/sublime-php-grammar) it has some indentation bug fixes and improvements. It will do what you need. It also has an indentation test suite, pull requests and opening issues are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

As @BullfrogBlues [mentions in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22509575/sublime-text-3-reindent-with-proper-array-parenthesis-in-php#comment42464239_22509575), the Sublime PHP Grammar plugin has a fix for this. I did not want that entire package, but fortunately it is very easy to extract out just the array indentation rule from there:

https://github.com/gerardroche/sublime-php-grammar/blob/master/Indentation%20Rules%20-%20Arrays.tmPreferences

Just save that file into the same directory where all your custom snippets etc. go (on Mac it's `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User`, not sure about Windows/Linux) and voila!

Answer (score 0):

The following solution was taken from [SublimeText Forum](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/php-array-indentation/5225/10).

Add this to your keybindings:

```
{ "keys": ["enter"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": { "contents": "\n\t$0\n" }, "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.auto_indent", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "punctuation.section.array.end.php", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "array\\($", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^\\)", "match_all": true },
    ]
},
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm using Sublime Text 3 and could solve this problem using the instructions on that page. I'm copying the same instructions here for reference, and I'll try to give some hints to find out why it isn't working for you.

First I've added those lines in my keybinding settings (Preferences -> Key bindings - User):

```
{ "keys": ["enter"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "Packages/User/Add Line in Braces.sublime-macro"}, "context":
  [
    { "key": "setting.auto_indent", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
    { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
    { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "\\($", "match_all": true },
    { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^\\)", "match_all": true }
  ]
}
```

You must pay attention here that this settings file is a JSON-Array, and the above code must written in brackets:

```
[
  // Copy above configuration here
]
```

If there are already some keybindings in your settings file, you must separate them with commas:

```
[
  {
    // Some existing keybindings
  },
  // Copy above configuration here
]
```

Then you should create a macro file in you user folder for Sublime Text 3. Where to find this folder depends on the operating system you are using. For instance, on Ubuntu it is:

> ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User

Create a new file in this folder, and name it (pay attention to cases and spaces):

> Add Line in Braces.sublime-macro

In this file, copy the following script and save:

```
[
    {"command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "\n\n"} },
    {"command": "left_delete", "args": null},
    {"command": "move", "args": {"by": "lines", "forward": false} },
    {"command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "hardeol", "extend": false} },
    {"command": "reindent", "args": {"single_line": true} }
]
```

This must be working, it works for me.